# How to find first set of duplicate characters with char pointers

Tags: c++

// EXAMPLE 1 RETURNS "Be happy now" gives "ppy now"

// Assume there is a set of duplicate letters

```
char * findDouble( char text[]){

    char *pText = text;
    char *currentChar;
    while((*pText) != '\0') {   
        if((*pText)==(*currentChar))
        {
            break;
        }

        *currentChar = *pText;
        pText++;
    }

    return pText;

}
```

What am I doing wrong? It returns nothing.

Comment: what do you mean with "it returns nothing" ? I does return `pText`. Can you show a [mcve] including how you call the functions and observe the "nothing return"?

Comment: One problem is that you're using `currentChar` before it's been set to a value in the first iteration of your loop.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Your compiler should warn you about using an uninitialized variable. If it does not, turn on (more) warnings, and *fix them*.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning `currentChar` to point anywhere before dereferencing it. You need something more like this instead:

```cpp
char *findDouble(char text[]) {
    char *pText = text;
    char *currentChar = pText+1;

    while (*pText != '\0') {
        if (*pText == *currentChar) {
            break;
        }
        ++currentChar;
        ++pText;
    }

    return pText;
}
```

However, you don't actually need that variable at all:

```cpp
char *findDouble(char text[]) {
    char *pText = text;

    while (*pText != '\0') {
        if (*pText == *(pText+1)) {
            break;
        }
        ++pText;
    }

    return pText;
}
```